# About the world as representation

Tags: metaphysics, metaphilosophy, schopenhauer

In "The World as Will and Representation", how can Schopenhauer say that the world is a representation if he himself EXISTS in his representation of the world? Isn't there a contradiction in his ideas?

Comment: No. Schopenhauer's world is a representation *and* the Will, the latter being its true form and the former a superficial seeming. What "exists" in this representation is not "he himself" but only some distorted trace, which is misidentified with the true reality - the Will in its 'individuations'. Similarly, in a videogame one "exists" through their avatar, but the avatar is not really "he himself" even if the one is  enthralled enough or delusional enough to identify with it.

Comment: Was Schopenhauer inspired by Taoism (the Tao as Will) ?

Comment: Close. He was influenced by Spinoza and later by Hinduism (Upanishads) and Buddhism with Brahman and Atman, maya and nirvana, see [SEP, The World as Will](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/schopenhauer/#4). Only his 'nirvana' has a rather mean streak with very pessimistic consequences for the prospects of enlightenment or salvation. Although there is a sort of 'bliss', or at least tranquility, one can achieve by cutting through the 'maya' and dispelling the Will's individuated urges.

Comment: Look in to Nonduality.